# JavaFX TextArea. The application crashes when using appendText too quickly. Any suggestion?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am updating the String content of a javafx.scene.control.**TextArea** from a different thread, adding a sentence at the time.

This is my listener method from where i append to the TextArea (named **display**):

```
public void onStatus(Status status) {
        if(userFilters.statusMatches(status)){
             display.appendText("@"
                 + status.getUser().getScreenName() + "\n"
                 + status.getText() + "\n-------------\n");
        }
}
```

If the rate of posting is not excessively quick, it works.

Otherwise, if the incoming messages are too many (e.g. public posts taken from a social network), the application 'graphical update' crash after a few of them.

The exceptions do not refers to any elements of the code I have written. So i do not know how to catch them and stop the application in a sort of clean way.

(By the way, I am not trying to append a null element.)

These are the exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:236)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.getRuns(Text.java:317)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.updatePGText(Text.java:1465)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_updatePeer(Text.java:1500)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_syncPeer(Node.java:503)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2290)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2419)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$122/1010826311.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:505)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(QuantumToolkit.java:334)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$41/1654631781.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.addTextRun(PrismTextLayout.java:755)
at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.addTextRun(GlyphLayout.java:121)
at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:770)
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1021)
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:223)
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:246)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Text.java:358)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_computeGeomBounds(Text.java:1168)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3556)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3509)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3457)
at javafx.scene.Node$MiscProperties$2.computeBounds(Node.java:6451)
at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9285)
at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9255)
at javafx.scene.Node.getBoundsInLocal(Node.java:3135)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin$ContentView.layoutChildren(TextAreaSkin.java:207)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1076)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$122/1010826311.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:505)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(QuantumToolkit.java:334)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$41/1654631781.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1063)
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:223)
at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:246)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Text.java:358)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_computeGeomBounds(Text.java:1168)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3556)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3509)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3457)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3620)
at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3403)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:538)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1706)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1706)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1706)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1706)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1706)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1706)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1706)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1706)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2404)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$122/1010826311.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:505)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(QuantumToolkit.java:334)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$41/1654631781.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

(...and so forth...)

Comment: can you show us the relevant code part where your other thread is updating the gui?

Comment: If TextArea is not mandatory for GUI, try Label or Text.

Answer (score 1):

Both exceptions are thrown because the variable `lines` is null inside `PrismTextLayout`. Why is this null? It is set to null every time you append text to the text area in this method (this is called by `append`):

```
com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.reset(PrismTextLayout.java:92)
```

The `lines` var isn't null normally because every time the scene is rendered it is reset. You are getting this NPE because you are calling between `lines` being set to null and being reset to its normal value.

The solution is to call `append` from the JavaFX app thread (i.e. use `runLater(() -> ...)` for appending to the TA).

Comment: The appendText method is already inside a thread launched using the Platform.runLater method.

Comment: But that is still a new thread, not the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: @MarcoMontaltoM. something else was editing the GUI from a non-GUI thread. the same thing happened to me and that was it. I'm posting this comment in hopes to help someone with the same issue I lost ten days on.